# How do I load DSA Parameters from a PEM file in Bouncycastle?

Tags: bouncycastle

I have a PEM file for DSA Parameters.  In other words, the content has header/footer like this:

`-----BEGIN DSA PARAMETERS-----
.......
-----END DSA PARAMETERS-----`

I see that bouncycastle has classes for `DSAParameters` and `DSAKeyGenerationParmaters`.  I suspect that this PEM is a representation of those parameters, but I can't figure out how to load it from a PEM format.

(Background: from legacy projects, I expected the signature of a DSA to be 40-bytes, but I am getting 46-bytes instead. I suspect that the DSA parameters are to blame, and I have this old dsa1024.pem as described, that I am trying to load and use to generate keys/generate signatures...)

Comment: Have you tried PEMReader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least through 1.57 (I don't have 1.58 installed yet) BCpkix `org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser` doesn't implement DSA PARAMETERS (although it DOES do EC PARAMETERS) so this won't be easy.
To just look at your parameters it will be (much) easier to use

```
 openssl dsaparam -in file -noout -text
```

But I guarantee you won't find anything wrong in your parameters. Classic DSA parameters have been 1024 bit group and 160 bit subgroup without any variation or change for 20 years and I've never seen any implementation get that wrong.

The usual reason a DSA-1024/160 signature occupies more than 40 octets is because by convention (though not required by FIPS 186) it is encoded in ASN.1 DER. If you had asked a question about that, I could point to you to existing Qs for ECDSA, which has exactly the same issue:

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1795/how-can-i-convert-a-der-ecdsa-signature-to-ASN.1 
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33095/shouldnt-a-signature-using-ecdsa-be-exactly-96-bytes-not-102-or-103
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37528/why-do-openssl-elliptic-curve-digital-signatures-differ-by-one-byte
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44988/length-of-ecdsa-signature

but since you asked a question that isn't about your actual problem it's against Stack policy to give you a solution to your actual problem.

FWIW if you generate a DSA *key(pair)* in OpenSSL using the parameters, all 4 PEM formats for privatekey (pkcs8 clear and encrypted, 'legacy' clear and encrypted) and the usual PEM format for publickey (SPKI) *are* readable by `PEMParser` and can produce key objects from which the parameters can be extracted. (Technically the specification for SPKI allows DSA parameters to be omitted in certain situations, but OpenSSL never does so.)

Comment: You are correct.  I quickly learned that my real issue is that bouncycastle gives me an asn.1 encoded signature, and I was expected the raw bytes...so I'll explore answers to those questions instead.